# SVN fix folder move done wrong

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Someone at my work moved a folder to a different location. But he didn't do a proper SVN move, he just added them as new files and deleted the old files. This of course meant the history of items are wrong. I was away at the time and several edits have happened on the files since, so reverting the revisions and redoing the operation myself is out.

Is there a way I can fix this up so SVN becomes aware of their full history?

P.S. I use tortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to edit the content of the history of a Subversion repository. You must either:

1. rebuild the repository starting from the pre-mistake revision, committing a correct move, and then committing the revisions from after that. This requires everyone to get new working copies, or rewind them (`svn update -rN`) to before the revisions that are going to be replaced.
2. Delete the moved folder, recreate it as a copy of the old folder (`svn copy <url of old dir>@<old rev> <new name in wc>`), then use `svn merge` to reapply the changes since then to the new copy of the old-location folder.

Comment: I'm confused about how I'm supposed to `svn merge` the changes if the first step is to delete the moved folder that contains the changes?

Comment: @StevenLiekens You merge _after_ copying in the old version of the folder.

Comment: Still confused. If I delete folder `newlocation\Foo@HEAD` and copy `oldlocation\Foo@<old rev>` to `newlocation\Foo` then what is there to merge?

Comment: @StevenLiekens You merge `<rev of mistake>:HEAD` to pick up changes that happened after the mistake and before you fix it.

Comment: So... merge the last committed revision (by its URL) with the working copy that is still in a modified state from overwriting it with files from `<old rev>`?

Comment: @StevenLiekens Merge takes a _range_. The range is from the mistake revision to HEAD (that being the revision just before you commit the fix). And yes, on top of the move. (I'm not absolutely sure that svn won't insist on you committing in-between; if it does, go ahead and do that. Then of course use the old head revision instead of HEAD for the endpoint of the range.)

Comment: I'm wondering if reposurgeon can do the job ? I've got not one but two hundred week histories to glue back to their origin.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [TortoiseSVN FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#getremovedfileback):

> If you have already committed the
>   deleted file, then you can use the
>   repository browser, change to the
>   revision where the file still existed
>   and then use the command Copy to...
>   from the context menu. Enter the path
>   to your working copy as the target and
>   the deleted file will be copied from
>   the repository to your working copy.
>
> **You can also restore a deleted directory using this technique.**

Of course, you have to delete (or rename) the folder added by your colleague first.

Answer (score 1):

From TortoiseSVN Help
http://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html

> Moving and renaming versioned files
>   inside a working copy must always be
>   done with the corresponding
>   Subversion/TortoiseSVN commands. A
>   move/rename without those (e.g., with
>   the Windows Explorer) leads to
>   problems since Subversion doesn't know
>   that you have moved/renamed the files.
>
> For example, if you rename a file
>   named myfile.txt to myfile2.txt
>   without using the
>   Subversion/TortoiseSVN command,
>   myfile.txt will show up as "missing"
>   and myfile2.txt as "non-versioned" in
>   the commit dialog or the
>   Check-For-Modifications dialog.
>
> If that happens to you, TortoiseSVN
>   offers you an easy way to correct
>   this.

As I know this is only way to repair move, Not sure about move_and_then_added though.

Comment: I don't think this is what he was asking.

Comment: Why not? just revert deletion and addition and repair move. hm ... loosing all history